# Connection manager with Ejb and restful?

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, ejb

I am making an application. The clients runs in android.The clients use username and password for connecting. I am interested how to connect the android client to the j2ee backend and how to tracking login session. Something like Stateless or stateful EJB and Restful would be perfect. **The big problem is how to manage login sessions in j2ee server.**
i am using Glassfish , volley (Google Api for android), and my two hands for type the codes.

Comment: You need to put some effort in to figuring this stuff out for yourself. The Java EE platform is extensively documented and there is a lot of information and examples available.

Comment: thanks @SteveC . i need to know the key concept and follow that.